# Using Image Transformation to create image sky view of what its like to be near black hole (Not a wormhole)

Tags: plotting, image-processing, physics, code-request

#### Question : I am trying to carry out point 3. "Implementing map" on page 13 in the paper [Interstellar wormholes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03809.pdf) using my own equations not those in the paper. however am not 100% sure on how to go about generating the numerical table of values and the image processing parts.

Note: I am using different equations to those given in the paper and thus the result will be different however the general method should be similiar therefore this is NOT the same answer as

I have generated the numerical map all I am trying to do is put this into the `ImageTransformation` or `ImageFowardTransformation` function, not entirely sure how to relate my interpolation function to the angles of a 2d image

```
numericalmap = {};
n = 100;
For[i = 0, i < n + 1, i++, \[Phi]csgen = (1.009 + (1/2) i/n)*Pi;
 M = 1; E0 = 1; \[Theta]cs = Pi/2;
 Nx = Sin[\[Theta]cs]*Cos[\[Phi]csgen];
 Ny = Sin[\[Theta]cs]*Sin[\[Phi]csgen];
 Nz = Cos[\[Theta]cs];
 nr = -Nx;
 n\[Phi] = -Ny;
 n\[Theta] = Nz;
 b = rc*Sin[\[Theta]c]*n\[Phi]/(1 - 2 M/rc)^(1/2);
 B2 = rc^2/(1 - 2 M/rc)*(n\[Phi]^2 + n\[Theta]^2);
 prinitial = ((1 - 2 M/rc)^(-1))*nr;
 p\[Theta]initial = ((1 - 2 M/rc)^(-1/2))*rc*n\[Theta];
 {rc, \[Theta]c, \[Phi]c} = {200, Pi/2, 0};
 lambdaend = -100000;
 ham = {
   t'[\[Lambda]] + E0/(1 - (2 M)/r[\[Lambda]]) == 0,
   r'[\[Lambda]] - (1 - (2 M)/r[\[Lambda]]) pr[\[Lambda]] == 0,
   \[Theta]'[\[Lambda]] - P\[Theta][\[Lambda]]/r[\[Lambda]]^2 == 0,
   \[Phi]'[\[Lambda]] - b/(r[\[Lambda]]*Sin[\[Theta][\[Lambda]]])^2 ==
     0, pr'[\[Lambda]] + 
     M/r[\[Lambda]]^2 (E0^2/(1 - (2 M)/r[\[Lambda]])^2 + 
        pr[\[Lambda]]^2) - B2/r[\[Lambda]]^3 == 0, 
   P\[Theta]'[\[Lambda]] - (b^2*
        Cos[\[Theta][\[Lambda]]])/(r[\[Lambda]]^2*
        Sin[\[Theta][\[Lambda]]]^3) == 0
   };
 haminital = {t[0] == 0, 
   r[0] == rc, \[Theta][0] == \[Theta]c, \[Phi][0] == \[Phi]c, 
   pr[0] == prinitial, P\[Theta][0] == p\[Theta]initial};
 \[Phi]2 = 
  NDSolveValue[{ham, haminital}, {t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi], pr, 
     P\[Theta]}, {\[Lambda], lambdaend, 0}][[4]];
 numericalmap = 
  Append[numericalmap, {\[Phi]csgen - Pi, Pi + \[Phi]2[lambdaend]}]]
```

Would appreciate any insight as how I could input this interpolation into `ImageTransformation` to get the desired effect.

I know Jason B attempted a similar problem but didn't use `ImageTransformation` for it.

When I put in some image of space the resulting images should look something like this:

[image: Black hole image]

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/lennrt/Interstellar-Wormhole-Ray-Tracing and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114155/9490

Comment: Thanks those are related I will have a look.

Comment: Duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110945/5601

Comment: No it isn't. That link addresses the case of using a wormholes geometry, I am interested in a black holes geometry. The methods however are similar though, except mine has different equations and would therefore have differences in end results.

Comment: @JasonB. I looked at those links you sent and they were very good. Just wondering would you be able to have a look at what I have done now? I am trying to use the `ImageTransformation` command to get resulting image deformations using my interpolation function I defined. Just not 100% sure on how to do it, I have some thoughts though and created another question on it https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192574/creating-a-numerical-table-of-values-and-using-an-interpolation-of-them-to-trans if you could have a look a that and share your views that would be great